# Get only part of uname -r in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, uname

I need to get only first two numbers of "uname -r" command in bash

example of regular out put:

```
uname -r
3.5.0-18-generic
```

what I expect using magic bash options:

```
3.5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming you want everything before the second dot, this will do what you want:

```
uname -r | cut -d. -f1-2
```

uname itself does not support cutting the output, afaik. The pipe through cut will show you fields 1 and 2 (`-f1-2`), delimited by dots (`-d.`)

Answer (score 3):

```
uname -r | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)\..*/\1/'
```

Comment: and do you know how can I capture this into a variable ?

Comment: I admit that using Yefim's solution is more efficient, it does not require sed.

Comment: @Ba7a7chy VER=$(uname -r | cut -d. -f1-2)

Answer (score 2):

You could also accomplish this with parameter expansion:

```
$ r="$(uname -r)"
$ echo ${r%.*}
3.5
```

`${VAR%pat}` non-greedily removes `pat` from the end of `VAR`. Note that `pat` is a glob pattern i.e. dot just means "dot" and star means "any-number-of-chars".